# QGIS Server does not display test WMS

Tags: wms, qgis-server, configuration, linux-mint

I'm having a similar problem to this post: [Using Qgis server with Ubuntu 12.04](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/32350/using-qgis-server-with-ubuntu-12-04)

I am using Mint 15 desktop and QGIS 2.0.1.

I read the above post and decided to go back a step or two and followed this tutorial: http://docs.qgis.org/2.0/html/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_ogc/ogc_server_support.html

I only got to the testing part. I am able to connect to localhost/cgi-bin/qgis_mapserv.fcgi using the 'Add WMS/WMST Layers' tool and I can see 'wfslayer' in the list. The 'Add' button is greyed out and the dialogue says Coordinate Reference System (0 available).

When I create my own QGIS project the 'Add' button is also greyed out unless I add the shapefile's CRS to Project Properties>'CRS Exclusions' list. If I add the CRS then I can add the layer to the TOC but it does not render.

I started to check if my web server (apache2) configuration was correct as per: http://karlinapp.ethz.ch/qgis_wms/configuration/index.html but am having the following issues:

1. I have two fcgid.conf so do I edit both?
2. I do not know the 'syntax' of 'DefaultInitEnv LD_LIBRARY_PATH' for apache2.conf or fcgid.conf
3. I used /usr/lib/qgis for QGIS libraries (is this correct?) but cannot determine the path to 'qt libraries'.

Do I need to configure these 3 conf files?

Are they the likely cause of not being able to add the test WMS layer?

Comment: Update: There is only one fcgid.conf file, which is symlinked. The log for my .QGS file: Map request error (Title:Service Exception; Error:Size error (Unknown error code)
The WMS vendor also reported: The requested map size is too large; URL: http://localhost/cgi-bin/project/qgis_mapserv.fcgi?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&BBOX=161523.15870953915873542,6390958.04735764022916555,335156.49165653850650415,6496786.19571453705430031&CRS=EPSG:28354&WIDTH=690&HEIGHT=421&LAYERS=TestURL&STYLES=&FORMAT=image/jpeg&DPI=96&MAP_RESOLUTION=96&FORMAT_OPTIONS=dpi:96)

Answer (score 3):

After much research and experimenting, including changing file permissions and removing relative file locations in the QGS file, I was unable to get qgis-server to serve a shapefile. I set up Postgis 2 and was successfully able to a serve a polygon layer. My conclusions are:

- That qgis_mapserv.fcgi as per my configuration that uses QGIS 2.0.1 doesn't work with shapefiles.
- The test WMS that is delivered with qgis_mapserv.fcgi is based on a shapefile and possibly why it doesn't work.
- qgis-server works with postgresql 9.1 and postgis 2.0.3 on Mint 15 (which is based on Ubuntu 13.04).
- The files fcgid.conf and apache.conf2 do not need configuring to test whether a map can be served using postgis.
- Not configuring Project Properties>OWS Server in a qgis project doesn't stop a layer being served.

Comment: Hey Colin. I´m having similiar errors and I´ll try it with PostGIS as you suggest. Thanks for sharing.